# How do i write an if statement to be between two values?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is my code, for my if statements I want to have it between two values for example:

```
if(rating < 5 > 2);
```

So I'm saying i want it to only print the command if that value is below 5 but higher than 2.
Is there a way to do this? Thank you for your time.

Here is my code.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What would you rate starcraft out of 10?");
        int rating = Console.Read();


        if (rating < 5) ;
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not good enough!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (rating > 5) ;
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OOOOOOOOO yeeeeeeee");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        if (rating > 8) ;
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We are bestfriends now ;)");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [conditional logical AND operator `&&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-):

```cs
if (rating < 5 && rating > 2)
{
}
```

Or [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#relational-patterns) ([read more #1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns), [read more #2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is)):

```cs
if (rating is < 5 and > 2)
{    
}
```

P.S.

You can refactor a bit with [`switch` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) and ordering the checks to remove some code repetition and improve readability (note that original code does not cover `rating == 5` case compared to the following):

```cs
var rating = ...;
var message = rating switch
{
    < 2 => "Terrible",
    < 5 => "Not good enough!",
    < 8 => "OOOOOOOOO yeeeeeeee",
    _ => "We are bestfriends now ;)"
};

Console.WriteLine(message);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @Aaron was glad to help! If any of provided answers works for you - please mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of it)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid complications, you can *sort* ratings' thresholds and then check them in order with a help of `if ... else if` pattern, e.g. having

```
   2 - Nightmare
   5 - Not good enough!
   8 - OOOOOOOOO yeeeeeeee
more - We are bestfriends now
```

We can put it as

```
if (rating <= 2) // 2 or less
  Console.WriteLine("Nightmare");
else if (rating <= 5) // (2..5]
  Console.WriteLine("Not good enough!");
else if (rating <= 8) // (5..8]
  Console.WriteLine("OOOOOOOOO yeeeeeeee");
else // more than 8
  Console.WriteLine("We are bestfriends now");
  
Console.ReadLine();
```